# Does Gamma function a solution for known Ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, gamma-function

It is well known that  [gamma function's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) defined as :
$$\Gamma \left( x \right) = \int\limits_0^\infty {s^{x - 1} e^{ - s} ds}$$
and it is divergent for
$x<0$. , Really I ask about differential equation which Gamma function satisfying it or by Other way : Does Gamma function a solution for known Ordinary differential equation and if yes what is it  ? For example if it obeyed any form of  $F( \Gamma, \Gamma ', \dots, \Gamma^{(k)}) = 0$ ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a well known result:
[Hölder's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_theorem)

Answer (score 3):

The gamma function  does not satisfy any **algebraic differential equation** . But it is the solution of the following **nonalgebraic differential equation**:
$$\frac{\partial w(x)}{\partial x}=w(x)~\psi(x);\qquad w(x)=\Gamma(x)$$

Otto Hölder proved in $1887$ that,

> The gamma function does not satisfy any algebraic differential equation

by showing that a solution to such an equation could not satisfy the gamma function's recurrence formula, making it a transcendentally transcendental function. This result is known as **Hölder's theorem**.